# SemanticUI pointing dropdown does not work correctly in Angular 2

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular2-template, semantic-ui

I as trying to make a pointing drop down, and it is as Semantic UI's documentation says it should be, but it didn't open to the side when I click,I might be missing something, can you guys help me?

```
<pre>
<div class="ui vertical menu">
  <div class="header item">
    Exemplos
  </div>
  <div class="ui left pointing dropdown link item">
    <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
    Imagem
    <div class="menu">
      <div class="item" routerLink="images" 
            RouterLinkActive="active">Reconhecimento de Objetos</div>
      <div class="item">Reconhecimento Facial</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</pre>
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

The Semantic UI dropdown module requires some JavaScript for it to work properly. To just get the menu to show, you can use angular to perform the necessary Javascript work.

```
<div class="ui vertical menu">
  <div class="header item">
    Exemplos
  </div>
  <div class="ui left pointing dropdown link item" ngClass="{'visible': showMenu, 'active': showMenu}">
    <i class="dropdown icon" (click)="showMenu = !showMenu"></i>
    Imagem
    <div class="menu" ngClass="{'visible': showMenu, 'hidden': !showMenu}">
      <div class="item" routerLink="images" 
            RouterLinkActive="active">Reconhecimento de Objetos</div>
      <div class="item">Reconhecimento Facial</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This won't apply the classes with the proper timing though to do the animations that Semantic UI provides as well. To do that you will have to load the requisite js libraries(jQuery and semantics js files) and get them to play nicely with Typescript.

Comment: I just obtained succes using ng2-semantic-ui one, but thx for your answer :D